# model.predict from keras is always returning the same result

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am trying a CNN model for mnist dataset. After training the model, it's giving 99% test accuracy by model.evaluate.
But when I try to predict the answer for one image, its always returning the same array when I call model.predict().

**Normalising the data:**

```
train_images = mnist_train_images.reshape(mnist_train_images.shape[0], 28, 28, 1)
test_images = mnist_test_images.reshape(mnist_test_images.shape[0], 28, 28, 1)
input_shape = (28, 28, 1)
    
train_images = train_images.astype('float32')
test_images = test_images.astype('float32')
train_images /= 255
test_images /= 255

#converting labels to one hot encoded format
train_labels = tensorflow.keras.utils.to_categorical(mnist_train_labels, 10)
test_labels = tensorflow.keras.utils.to_categorical(mnist_test_labels, 10)
```

**Model Structure and Model Training:**

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                 activation='relu',
                 input_shape=input_shape))
# 64 3x3 kernels
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
# Reduce by taking the max of each 2x2 block
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
# Dropout to avoid overfitting
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
# Flatten the results to one dimension for passing into our final layer
model.add(Flatten())
# A hidden layer to learn with
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
# Another dropout
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
# Final categorization from 0-9 with softmax
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
with tensorflow.device('/device:GPU:0'):
  model.fit(train_images, train_labels,
                    batch_size=128,
                    epochs=7,
                    verbose=2,
                    validation_data=(test_images, test_labels))
```

Now, I have a black and white (28,28) image of a digit(Actually, its a digit from mnist training data itself). Trying to predict after normalizing that image:

```
image = image.reshape(-1,28, 28,1)
image = image.astype('float32')
image/=255

pred_array = model.predict(image)
print(pred_array)
pred_array = np.argmax(pred_array)
print('Result: {0}'.format(pred_array))
```

This always gives the same pred_array every time, and of course wrong.
I tried the answers to similar questions. For example, tried increasing epochs,
also one answer said to do

```
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D,MaxPooling2D
```

instead of

```
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten, Conv2D,MaxPooling2D
```

Tried everything but nothing seems to help. Maybe, my normalising of the image is wrong, or I might've made some silly mistake as I am new to working with images and using CNN. Please Help

Comment: What is the result of `print` of `pred_array`? and what is the shape of the image?

Comment: @GiYeonShin print of pred_array is `[[1.94893827e-17 2.04633741e-10 1.09332424e-13 9.99999881e-01
  2.65823266e-14 3.67422288e-08 8.79753565e-17 1.44412160e-09
  9.73693626e-11 6.05738819e-08]]` and the shape of image after normalising is (1,28,28,1). Btw I have accepted an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just replicated the code and everything works fine. I hope you are not loading the test image from normalized train_images because images in there are already normalized and you normalizing it again before predicting. Following works as expected for me:

```python
image = train_images[14]
image = image.astype('float32')
image = image.reshape(-1,28, 28,1)
image/=255
pred_array = model.predict(image)
print(pred_array)
pred_array = np.argmax(pred_array)
print('Result: {0}'.format(pred_array))
```

**Edit:**
I did something different when I was replicating your code. I kept normalized images in different Numpy array like this:

```python
train_images_norm = train_images.astype('float32')
test_images_norm = test_images.astype('float32')
train_images_norm /= 255
test_images_norm /= 255
...
model.fit(train_images_norm, train_labels_norm,...)
```

So now, when I predict I use original images(not normalized) ones and normalize them before prediction. The reason you get unpredictable results is that you are dividing already normalized images by 255 again which creates completely different numbers that the network is not trained with. You have two options, either keep the original images in different array and normalize them before prediction (My code) or if you want your original code to work you can remove `image = image.astype('float32')` and `image /= 255` before prediction.

Comment: I don't think reposting code and saying "works for me" should qualify as an answer. Best left as a comment. I won't flag it but it should probably be moved to comment instead.

Comment: The code provided by the user works as expected. A possible problem with the user prediction method is given, and the code is not re-posted but modified version that actually works as the user expects. Although the diffidence is one line of code, but that is what the user is most likely mistaken about since he/she did not provide how the image value is loaded.

Comment: @NimaAghli You are also using train_images  in your code. And, by normalising I meant converting to float32, reshaping,dividing by 255, which all you also did.
I am getting this output:

[[0.09712957 0.12846719 0.10435061 0.09085704 0.09937355 0.09544346
  0.09477601 0.10677139 0.08749077 0.09534037]]
Result: 1
For different images too

Comment: I did was something different when I replicated the code that I did not mention. I edited my answer. Please take a look!

Comment: @NimaAghli Thanks a lot, Normalising in different array helped. My output is correct now.